# How to disable bash messages when using PyIDL?

Tags: python, bash, printing, idl

I have a code that imports PyIDL and runs a specific method. But everytime shows compiling messages, which is kind of annoying when I want other informations printed together.

```
import pidly    
idl = pidly.IDL()
idl("p_read, '"+pathIMG+"', h, p")
idl("header = h")
```

A example:

> % Compiled module: P_READ.
>
> % Compiled module: P_RHEAD.
>
> % Compiled module: P_PDS_RHEAD.
>
> ...

So, how could I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control these things from IDL:

```
idl('!quiet = 1')
```

But, be warned that this will also disable other informational message besides just the compiled messages, i.e., anything like:

```
message, 'this is an informational message', /informational
```

It will not disable error messages.